# File reading problem

Tags: ruby, io

```
f = File.open("/test/serverlist.txt", "r")
list = f.readlines
list.each do|servers|
  File.open('/test/results.txt','w') do |b|
  servers.each do |p|
    r = `ping -n 1 #{p}`
    b.puts r
  end
end
```

It reads the `serverlist` file, and returns a string. The `serverlist` file contains the following IP addresses:

```
192.168.150.254
192.168.120.2
```

Comment: Your probleme is not clear! Tell us what do you want in ouput

Comment: I want to output the results of the ping to a file. I am trying to use the serverlist contents )IP addresses as the servers to ping

Comment: Please don't make us guess what is wrong. Take the time to clearly explain what you want your code to do, and why it is not doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking to read each line from the file and then do something with like this.

```
fout = File.open('/test/results.txt','w')
File.open("/test/serverlist.txt", "r").each_line do |server|
   server.chomp!
   r = `ping -n 1 #{server}`
   fout.puts r
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will need to iterate over the server line itself, and with a few style mods added and ping(1) arguments changed, I would suggest...

```
open 'serverlist.txt', 'r' do |f|
  open '/tmp/results.txt', 'w' do |b|
    f.readlines.each do |server|
      b.puts `ping -c 1 -t 1 #{server}`
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use b.write in place of b.puts

Answer (score 0):

if you're using linux you could just go for

```
File.open("serverlist.txt").each { |addy| `echo "#{`ping -c 1 #{addy}`}" >> result.txt` }
```

and be done with it

well .. maybe add

```
`echo "# server-availability" > result.txt`
```

before the above line so the file gets reset every time you call this